# How do I bind different properties of an Editor to the same variable based on the platform in Xamarin (XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to bind the property `PlainText` (**which is a TwoWay Bindable property which I created in my CustomEditor**) of `CustomEditor` to the variable `KeyString` when on `iOS`, and bind the property `Text` to `KeyString` when on `Android`.

I know that the binding of `PlainText` to `KeyString` when on `iOS` works properly (I have tested to ensure this), however the binding of `Text` to `KeyString` for `Android` fails with **`System.ArgumentNullException`** **`Value cannot be null. Parameter name: binding`**

Also **IntelliSense** underlines the parts of my code that use `BindingBase` in `x:TypeAgruments`. For the first part Intellisense says: `PlainText does not support values of type OnPlatform(BindingBase)`, but the code still works when I run it on my `iOS` emulator. It gives me the error `Text does not support values of type OnPlatform(BindingBase)` for the `Android` binding part of the code and that is the part of my XAML which it fails to run.

Below is my `XAML` code, any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
<Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderColor="Black" Margin="0" Padding="0">
     <controls:CustomEditor HeightRequest="80" IsPassword="True">
         <controls:CustomEditor.PlainText>
             <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="BindingBase">
                 <On Platform="iOS" Value="{Binding KeyString}"/>
             </OnPlatform>
         </controls:CustomEditor.PlainText>

         <controls:CustomEditor.Text>
             <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="BindingBase">
                 <On Platform="Android" Value="{Binding KeyString}"/>
             </OnPlatform>
         </controls:CustomEditor.Text>

         <controls:CustomEditor.Effects>
             <controls:PasswordEffect>
             </controls:PasswordEffect>
         </controls:CustomEditor.Effects>
     </controls:CustomEditor>
</Frame>
```

In my custom Editor class I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.CustomControls
{
    public class CustomEditor : Editor
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsPasswordProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsPassword), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomEditor), false);

        public static readonly BindableProperty PlainTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlainText),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CustomEditor),
                String.Empty,
                defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged:OnPlainTextChanged);

        public bool IsPassword
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPasswordProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsPasswordProperty, value); }
        }

        public string PlainText {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlainTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlainTextProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnPlainTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (CustomEditor)bindable;
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                control.PlainText = newValue.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't set the text accordingly to the platform in your CustomEditor? In that case, you can just bind your values to the property and handle platform in your control

Comment: what is CustomEditor? is there a viewmodel? [m.v.c.e] please

Comment: @lawiluk thanks for the comment, it sounds like a reasonable idea, could you explain further? on how to do this

Comment: I just test your code with a simple binding and it works on Android side, can you share more code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have shared some more code, hope that will help, let me know if there is something more specific you want to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't like working with `OnPlatform`, I'd like to propose a workaround that I've mentioned in the comment.

In you `CustomEditor` add the following code:

```cs
public static BindableProperty CustomTitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: nameof(CustomTitle),
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(CustomEditor),
    defaultValue: null);

public string CustomTitle
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CustomTitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CustomTitleProperty, value); }
}

protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    if(propertyName==CustomTitleProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        SetCustomTitle();
    }
}

private void SetCustomTitle()
{
    switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
    {
        case Device.iOS:
            {
                PlainText = CustomTitle;
                return;
            }
        case Device.Android:
            {
                Text = CustomTitle;
                return;
            }
        default:
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{Device.RuntimePlatform} not supported in {nameof(SetCustomTitle)}");
            }
    }
}
```

What I did there is I simply moved OnPlatform code to your control, so you can keep your xaml code cleaner.

With this approach you should be able to use it like

```xml
<controls:CustomEditor HeightRequest="80" IsPassword="True" CustomTitle="{Binding KeyString}">
     <controls:CustomEditor.Effects>
         <controls:PasswordEffect/>
     </controls:CustomEditor.Effects>
</controls:CustomEditor>
```

Comment: very helpful, thanks a lot, this led me on the right path to fix the issue and get my code cleaner.

Comment: Happy to help you!

Answer (score 1):

The x:TypeArguments of OnPlatform represents the type of Value that you are going to bind, in your case `KeyString` is of type `string`. Take a look at [OnPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform).

```
<Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderColor="Black" Margin="0" Padding="0">
     <controls:CustomEditor HeightRequest="80" IsPassword="True">
         <controls:CustomEditor.PlainText>
             <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="{x:Type x:String}">
                 <On Platform="iOS" Value="{Binding KeyString}"/>
             </OnPlatform>
         </controls:CustomEditor.PlainText>

         <controls:CustomEditor.Text>
             <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="{x:Type x:String}">
                 <On Platform="Android" Value="{Binding KeyString}"/>
             </OnPlatform>
         </controls:CustomEditor.Text>

         <controls:CustomEditor.Effects>
             <controls:PasswordEffect>
             </controls:PasswordEffect>
         </controls:CustomEditor.Effects>
     </controls:CustomEditor>
</Frame>
```

Comment: The IntelliSense error should go away...
Please provide the platform code for more details

Comment: unfortunately it does not remove the IntelliSense error, and it does not build successfully either, (using `BindingBase` builds successfully, and runs fine when the `CustomEditor.Text` part is removed, hence why I believe that is where the issue comes from). Did you want to see the code for the effect or the renderer(s)?